# Python: Bokeh hover tool tips date time

Tags: python, datetime-format, bokeh

I am trying to get a line plot via Bokeh in Python. I am new to Bokeh and I am trying to apply hover tool tips over the plot. The x-axis of the plot has Timestamp values which are converted into epoch string. I've reviewed some same problems here and tried to use the workaround for my case but it doesn't seem to work. On the plot it gives `???` where the time should show up.

Any suggestions for my code?

Timestamp is in format `2016-12-29 02:49:12`

Also can someone tell how do I format x-axis ticks to show up vertically ?

```
p = figure(width=1100,height=300,tools='resize,pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,previewsave,hover',logo=None)
p.title.text = "Time Series for Price in Euros"
p.grid.grid_line_alpha = 0
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Day"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "Euros"
p.ygrid.band_fill_color = "olive"
p.ygrid.band_fill_alpha = 0.1
p.circle(df['DateTime'],df['EuP'], size=4, legend='close',
      color='darkgrey', alpha=0.2)
p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(formats=dict(
    hours=["%d %B %Y"],
    days=["%d %B %Y"],
    months=["%d %B %Y"],
    years=["%d %B %Y"],
))


source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(time=[x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")for x in df['DateTime']]))
hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = {"time":'@time', "y":"$y"}
hover.mode = 'mouse'
p.line(df['DateTime'],df['EuP'],legend='Price',color='navy',alpha=0.7)
```